# Problem with background change when the component is focused

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a components that needs to change its background color when focused, but for whatever reason it doesn't work. The hover is working pretty well, but the focus isn't. Can you guys help me?

```
import { CardContainer } from './styles'

interface CheckoutFormCardProps {
  icon: JSX.Element
  cardType: string
}

export function CheckoutFormCard({ icon, cardType }: CheckoutFormCardProps) {
  return (
    <CardContainer>
      <input type="radio" name="typeOfPayment" value={cardType} />
      {icon}
      <span>{cardType}</span>
    </CardContainer>
  )
}
```

Also, here's the style file:

```
import { styled } from 'styled-components'

export const CardContainer = styled.label`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.75rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: ${(props) => props.theme['base-button']};
  flex: 1 0 0;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background 0.2s;

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    padding: 0.75rem;
    width: 100%;
  }

  &:hover {
    background: ${(props) => props.theme['base-hover']};
  }

  input[type='radio']:checked + label {
    background: props.theme.purple;
  }

  input {
    display: none;
  }

  svg {
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.purple};
  }
`
```

Already tried to create an outer div container but it didn't work as well. I've thought on creating a state but it seems a little too much for such small change.

Comment: Excuse me, but shouldn't you pass <CardContainer theme={theme}> to pass the props to the styled components?
Also the focus you expect is on input[type='radio']:checked + label {
     background: props.theme.purple;
   } or on a &:focus?

Comment: @gianninho, the theme props isn't needed because i'm using the ThemeProvider wrapper component native from the styled lib. I'm expecting a background change on a &:focus. Also, I've already tried to use input[type='radio']:checked + label ~ & { background: props.theme.purple; } but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a label component to wrap the input, you may have problems applying the :focus style directly to the label element. This is because the label element itself may not receive focus the way interactive elements such as inputs do.

You have two solutions:

1. Make label interactive, adding tabIndex to CardContainer and &:focus in styles:

   ```
   import { CardContainer } from './styles'

   interface CheckoutFormCardProps {
       icon: JSX.Element
       cardType: string
   }

   export function CheckoutFormCard({ icon, cardType }: CheckoutFormCardProps) {
   return (
       <CardContainer tabIndex={0}>
           <input type="radio" name="typeOfPayment" value={cardType} />
           {icon}
           <span>{cardType}</span>
       </CardContainer>
     )
   }
   ```

   and add in your styles:

   ```
    &:focus {
        background: ${(props) => props.theme['base-focus']};
    }
   ```
2. Instead of using :focus on the label element, you can try using :focus-within on the entire CardContainer component to handle styling when an inner element gets focus. :focus-within fires when at least one child element has focus.

   ```
    &:focus-within {
        background: ${(props) => props.theme['base-focus-within']};
    }
   ```

   But this of course only works if you have **input with display not none**.

Let me know if it can works.